# Ubuntu 12.10 WIFI card not activated

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

I have a Dell XPS-15 on Ubuntu 12.10 with a wifi card Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235.
I don't know why but I don't have access to wifi anymore, my card is detected but I can't activate it.

Here is the output I get for some commands:

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 07
   serial: d4:be:d9:6c:c7:27
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=130.104.228.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:46 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d2404000-d2404fff memory:d2400000-d2403fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 24
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d2600000-d2601fff
```

And from iwconfig

```
iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I don't know why wlan0 is not shown anymore.

When I try to activate it I get the following error message:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Can someone tell me how I can activate my wifi card?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same problem on another laptop and you can try this:
sudo rfkill list

you'll know if your wifi card is not restricted

then you could try install compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc

sorry for my english.:)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer.
I get the following code:
    'sudo rfkill list
    1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no'

But I don't know where you found your compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc package

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential

wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
tar xvf compat*
cd compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc
sudo su
./scripts/driver-select ath9k
make
make install
modprobe ath9k
exit

it's complete process give me a reasult..

Comment: Hello, I followed your instructions and when I run `modprobe ath9k` and got WARNING: Error inserting ath9k_hw (/lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko): Invalid argument
WARNING: Error inserting ath9k_common (/lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko): Invalid argument
WARNING: Error inserting mac80211 (/lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko): Invalid argument
FATAL: Error inserting ath9k (/lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko): Invalid argument